How to Install extensions.blender.org addons to custom directory?
I want to know if there is a way to install the extensions.blender.org addons to a custom directory, because currently it installs to the %appdata% and that is highly inconvenient for me as I have to switch PC's at times. I am currently using blender 4.3
Looking forward to your reply.
Cheers.
Edit 1: I specifically want to retain the auto-update feature provided via the official extensions platform.

This question is similar to: How do I change the location where addons are saved? Windows Blender 4.0+. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/deploying_blender.html#bundling-extensions might also be relevant.

@MartynasŽiemys the older thread only applies to legacy addons. My question is related specifically to addons installed from the official extensions platform of blender. I can install non blender.org extensions to a custom blender directory fine. If i try that with blender.org extensions, i lose the auto update option.

In Preferences > Get Extensions, open the Repositories Popup. Select the extensions.blender.org repository.
Open the Advanced panel, enable "Custom Directory", and set the path to your liking:

